Determine if a number is in the Fibonacci sequence using Binet's formula
I am wondering how to identify a Fibonacci number using Binet's formula. One of the approaches I tried was:
Using Binet's formula, $$F_n=\frac{\varphi^{n}-(-1)^n\varphi^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
I multiply the equation by $\sqrt{5}$, and by solving the quadratic, I get $$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n\sqrt{5}\pm\sqrt{5F_n+4(-1)^n}}{2}$$
I have done this by using wikipedia as my reference, but I don’t know how to get this:
$$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}=\frac{(F_n\sqrt{5}+F_n+2F_{n-1})}{2}$$

I have tried doing the following:
Using Binet’s formula,
$$\varphi^n=\frac{F_n\sqrt{5}\pm\sqrt{5F_n^2+4(-1)^n}}{2}=\frac{F_n5\sqrt{5}\pm5\sqrt{5F_n^2+4(-1)^n}}{10}$$
Using the formula:$\left(\frac{\varphi^n-(-1)^n\varphi^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)  $,
$$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}$$
$$=\left(\frac{\varphi^n-(-1)^n\varphi^{1-n}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\varphi+\left(\frac{\varphi^{n-1}-(-1)^n\varphi^{1-n}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\varphi^{n+1}-2[(-1)^n\varphi^{1-n}]-\varphi^{n-1}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$=\frac{\varphi(F_{n+1}-F_{n-1})-2[(-1)^n\varphi^{1-n}]}{\sqrt{5}}$$
This boxed part in the image is the part I’m confused with.
Can you please explain to me how to get the boxed part? Thanks!

$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}$ is on the wiki proven in the section just before this one

I am confused on how to derive $$\varphi^n=F_n+F_{n-1}=\frac{(F_n\sqrt{5}+F_n+2F_{n-1})}{2}$$

@WashingtonFig You are asking for the proof of $\varphi^n = F_n \varphi + F_{n-1}$, right? If not, then it means you do not even know the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$.

Once you have $\varphi^n = F_n \varphi + F_{n-1}$, just use $\varphi = (\sqrt{5}+1)/2$ to get
$$ \varphi^n = F_n \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} + F_{n-1} = \frac{F_n \sqrt{5} + F_n + 2 F_{n-1}}{2}$$

I don't think it provides the answer to the given question. The question owner asks for the proof of $\varphi^n = F_n \varphi + F_{n-1}$.

@Pustam Raut I was confused on how $F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}=\frac{F_n\sqrt{5}+F_n+2F_{n-1}}{2}$ I did not realise that you can treat the golden ratio as known and could be directly substituted in to the equation. Thank you very much for your answer though!

@WashingtonFig Unbelievable! You know how to get $\varphi^n=F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}$, and you are confused about this simple substitution $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$.

@WashingtonFig You're most welcome!

Binet's formula:
$$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt5}$$
where $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2$ is the conjugate of the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.
We have, $\varphi\psi=-1$ and $\varphi^2=\varphi+1$ or $\varphi=1+1/\varphi$.
Now,
$$\begin{aligned}
F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}&=\frac{\varphi^{n+1}-\varphi\psi\cdot\psi^{n-1}}{\sqrt5}+\frac{\varphi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}{\sqrt5}\\&=\frac{\varphi^{n}(\varphi+1/\varphi)+\psi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}{\sqrt5}\\&=\varphi^n\cdot\frac{2\varphi-1}{\sqrt5}\qquad\text{since}~\frac1\varphi=\varphi-1\\F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}&=\varphi^n\qquad\text{proved.}
\end{aligned}$$
It is the decomposition of higher powers of the golden ratio $\varphi^n$ as a linear combination of the golden ratio $\varphi$ and $1$, with Fibonacci numbers as the linear coefficients.
Substituting the value of the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ on the right-hand side of $\varphi^n = F_n \varphi + F_{n-1}$, we get
$$\color{blue}{\varphi^n=F_n\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)+F_{n-1}=\frac{(F_n\sqrt{5}+F_n+2F_{n-1})}{2}}$$
I hope this helps.

$\varphi^n=F_n\varphi+F_{n-1}$ can be also proved by the mathematical induction as follows: $\varphi^{n+1} = (F_n\varphi + F_{n-1})\varphi = F_n\varphi^2 + F_{n-1}\varphi = F_n(\varphi+1) + F_{n-1}\varphi = (F_n + F_{n-1})\varphi + F_n = F_{n+1}\varphi + F_n.$
